# Get InnertText from event click button (for GTM)

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I tried to get innerText from a click button with js event
for exemple :

```html
<label class="sc-AxirZ haYsgf">
  <span>brouh</span>
  <span></span>
  <input type="radio" name="bruh" value="bruh1">
</label>
<label class="sc-AxirZ haYsgf">
  <span>test</span>
  <span></span>
  <input type="radio" name="bruh1" value="bruh2">
</label>
<label class="sc-AxirZ haYsgf">
  <span>test2</span>
  <span></span>
  <input type="radio" name="bruh3" value="bruh4">
</label>
```

I would like to get the value of the button when I clicked on it. (get "moins de 20 ans" if I clicked on it)
The only one prob it's, I've more than one button with the same class

Can you help me, please?
I try to do this for Google Tag Manager to get values.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Attach event listeners to the radio buttons and call a function when they change.

```js
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

radios.forEach(radio => radio.addEventListener('change', handleChange, false));

function handleChange(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

```html
<label class="sc-AxirZ haYsgf"><span>Moins de 25 ans</span><span></span><input type="radio" name="BAS110Q" value="BAS110R01"></label>
<label class="sc-AxirZ haYsgf"><span>Moins de 20 ans</span><span></span><input type="radio" name="BAS110Q" value="BAS110R02"></label>
<label class="sc-AxirZ haYsgf"><span>Moins de 29 ans</span><span></span><input type="radio" name="BAS110Q" value="BAS110R03"></label>
```

Alternatively you can wrap your radio buttons in a container and apply the event listener to that element.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container');

container.addEventListener('change', handleChange, false);

function handleChange(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <label class="sc-AxirZ haYsgf"><span>Moins de 25 ans</span><span></span><input type="radio" name="BAS110Q" value="BAS110R01"></label>
  <label class="sc-AxirZ haYsgf"><span>Moins de 20 ans</span><span></span><input type="radio" name="BAS110Q" value="BAS110R02"></label>
  <label class="sc-AxirZ haYsgf"><span>Moins de 29 ans</span><span></span><input type="radio" name="BAS110Q" value="BAS110R03"></label>
</div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: I can't modify this HTML (is not my website)

Comment: i don't have a container in my html, it's a simple div with another div, look at this website https://www.codageparis.com/fr/diagnostic/questions#/

Comment: Like I said, the first example will still work.

Comment: i've this http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2021/26/2/1624958921-stack.jpg

Comment: Then something else is happening. My code is based on your HTML.

Comment: I added a picture for you, if u want to help me again :)